# GoogleTest force #undef on particular test

Tags: c, embedded, googletest

I use GoogleTest, and I want to test some functions with #ifndef inside.

file a.c

```
bool myFunction() {
#ifndef FOO
   return true;
#else   
   return false;
#endif
}
```

Is it possible to force an #undef during a particular test ? Like that I can test the function in the 2 stats (with the define and without).

Comment: I think your question is, is it possible to recompile the source file during a Google test, and I think not.

Comment: Because you can replace some function inside test with MOCK, I hope there is something for define too

Comment: The problem is that `FOO` is a preprocessor symbol. Whether or not it is defined.... is a question that is only meaningful during compilation of the code. So, in order to get what you want, we need a mechanism by which Google Test will compile two versions of your test, one with the define and one without. I'm not sure that such a utility exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of the reasons why people try to avoid having multiple versions of a function that you create with `#define`, `#if`, etc. It’s hard to test all these different versions.

If you want to test both versions, you must compile your program twice (one with `#define FOO` and once without), and then run the tests separately. The only way to change the value of `FOO`, as written, is to recompile the program.

Alternatively, you can refactor your code so the `#define` is unnecessary.

Comment: I use many #define because I work on embedded system, and I need many optimization, and preprocessor it's a good way to do that. Refactoring code, it's not option, I try to convince my co-workers to implement unit tests, if we have to refactor the code, there answers will be NO.

Comment: @P.Paul-Alexandre - So your company produced a codebase full of conditionally compiled bits and pieces, without incorporating testing into your original deployment process? Ouch

Comment: no unit test doesn't mean no test at all. @DietrichEpp compile the program twice could be a good idea, thanks.